# How do I compress base64 data using stringIO into a buffer?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Working on this challenge for my Python course and cant seem to figure out how to continue. I think what i have so far is correct but any input would be amazing.

Goal: Decode the base64 blob included below

```
import base64
import gzip
import StringIO

# This is our base64 encoded string
data = 'H4sIAAAAAAAAAL1X6W+j....'

def main():
    # Decode the base64 string into a variable
    decoded = base64.b64decode(data)
    # Create a variable that holds a stream living in a buffer

    # Decompress our stream

    # Print it to the screen

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: where im stuck ( assuming the #decode is correct, is the three final tasks

Comment: what have you tries so far

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to write out the StringIO function and then decompress it. Admittedly im still learning so forgive me if the answer is ridiculously simple. I know the StringIO will out into a buffer then the gzip will decompress, i just cant put together how it should look?

Comment: @kermitwdahoodie: Read the `StringIO` docs and `gzip` docs? They have examples, and tying them together isn't that hard. If this is for a class, you should really try to get it working yourself before asking us to do it; you'll learn it a lot better that way.

Comment: This is just read called on gzip.GzipFile applied to a StringIO applied to decoded.

Comment: Going through the docs suggested above now. Not trying to cheat just trying to get a grasp on arrangement and what not. I appreciate the links!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with detailed explanation

```
#Going by the comments in your code
#content of data variable is first gzip compressed and then base64 encoded
#In order to get the original content back, you must, 
#first base64 decode and then gzip uncompress it

#since gzip works on file objects, StringIO is to be used 
#StringIO module implements a file-like class, that reads and writes a string buffer 

import StringIO
import base64
import gzip

data = "...." #gzip compressed => base64 encoded
b64decoded = base64.b64decode(data) # base64 decode 
inputstream = StringIO.StringIO();
inputstream.write(b64decoded)
inputstream.seek(0)
#
uncompressGzip = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=inputstream, mode='rb') # gzip uncompress
originalData = uncompressGzip.read()
print(originalData)
```

Here is a simple test, compress => encode => decode => uncompress

```
import StringIO
import base64
import gzip

buf = StringIO.StringIO()
compressGzip = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf, mode="wb")
compressGzip.write("Hello, how are you?")
compressGzip.close()
buf.seek(0)
data = base64.b64encode(buf.getvalue())
# your solution from this point onwards
b64decoded = base64.b64decode(data) # base64 decode 
inputstream = StringIO.StringIO();
inputstream.write(b64decoded)
inputstream.seek(0)
#
uncompressGzip = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=inputstream, mode='rb') # gzip uncompress
originalData = uncompressGzip.read()
print(originalData)
```

Comment: Each use of `x = StringIO.StringIO(); x.write(SOMETHING); x.seek(0)` could be replaced with just `x = StringIO.StringIO(SOMETHING)`. You're allowed to pass the initial contents as an argument to the constructor. In the case of `outputstream`, you don't need `StringIO` at all, you could just do `originalData = uncompressGzip.read()`; `StringIO` is completely superfluous.

Comment: @ShadowRanger absolutely correct, you can omit use of outputstream and directly read.